# Install software from all subdirectories

Tags: shell-script, software-installation, tar

I'm somewhat new to Ubuntu and I installed it to do a small project. I extracted about 30 tar archives with packages in them and now I have a lot of directories, each containing the source code and a `configure` file.

**How can I quickly loop through all the subdirectories and run the configure shell script in each one?**

So far, I have tried creating a shell script (called i.sh) that loops through the folders and runs the configure script, but to no avail. Is there any way it can be corrected? And how would I execute it?

```
find . -type d | while read d; do
    ./configure
    make
    sudo make install
done
```

I executed it by going into the terminal and running `sudo bash ./i.sh`.

Thank you!

Comment: You did not`cd` into the directory before running `configure`. Remember to `cd` back to the original directory at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over all directories in the current directory, use a simpler loop:

```
for dir in ./*/; do
   # more here
done
```

The pattern `./*/` would match subdirectories in the current directory.

Using `find` would most likely do the wrong thing here as it would find subdirectories in the unpacked `tar` archives.

For each directory, `$dir`, you want to `cd` into that directory and do the build:

```
for dir in ./*/; do
    ( cd "$dir" && ./configure && make && sudo make install )
done
```

The parenthesis makes the commands run in a subshell. The change of the directory inside the subshell will not be reflected outside of the subshell, so there's never a need to "`cd` back".

I've strung together the commands with `&&` ("and").  This means that if one command fails, the later commands would not be run at all.

You would not execute this with `sudo`, as the only step that might *possibly* need root privileges is the `make install` step, which is already prefixed by `sudo`.

Note that this would install all the projects under `/usr/local` by default.  To install in another installation prefix, use e.g. `--prefix=$HOME/local` with `configure` (which means you would not need `sudo` *at all*, since you in already have write permissions in your home directory).

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I needed.